# Unable to install Photoshop on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wine, photoshop

I have tried many of the suggestions that I found online, but I always run into a problem. I use Play on Linux to install Photoshop 6 on my Ubuntu 16.04, but when it gets to the point of downloading `windowsxp-kb936929-sp3-x86-enu` (followed by a long name with an `.exe` extension), it stays there forever. It only says 316.4 0f 316.4 MB downloaded, the progress bar remains static, and that is the end of it.

Would somebody please help?
I was able to run it before, but since I reinstalled the OS, I get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's clearly a windows XP executable (don't ask me what it does). Photoshop 6 will run in Windows 7 as well, so run *winecfg* in terminal and set the default operating system to Windows 7 before installing. It won't need XP service pack 3 so you might have more luck.